# datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 6, 1, 44, 44, tzinfo=<UTC>) django

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-rest-framework

When i create my Model serializer with django-rest-framework and try to get from URL i got the next error

> 'unicode' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'

But when i execute the shell of django

```
a = Model.objects.all()[0:1]
a[0].upload_date
```

This is printed in shell

> datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 6, 1, 44, 44, tzinfo=)

The field in the model

```
upload_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

The serializer

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Reports
        fields = '__all__'
```

I don't know how serialize this field

Comment: Can you show the traceback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    upload_date = serializers.DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        model = Reports
        fields = ('upload_date',)
```

more info http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datetimefield

Comment: If I want to put all the fields, is it necessary to put them one by one? Or exists another method?